# Enums in Solidity

Tags: solidity, solc

Enum's are not working in solc? Just tried to compile demo contract from gihub documentation :

```
contract test {
  enum ActionChoices { GoLeft, GoRight, GoStraight, SitStill };
  function test()
  {
     choices = ActionChoices.GoStraight;
  }
  function getChoice() returns (uint d)
  {
     d = uint256(choices);
  }
  ActionChoices choices;
}
```

And getting error:

```
Error: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.
enum ActionChoices { GoLeft, GoRight, GoStraight, SitStill };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems that if semicolon is removed, it works. Contract should look like:

```
contract test {
  enum ActionChoices { GoLeft, GoRight, GoStraight, SitStill }
  function test()
  {
     choices = ActionChoices.GoStraight;
  }
  function getChoice() returns (uint d)
  {
      d = uint256(choices);
  }
  ActionChoices choices;
}
```